# Create a new column from existing columns where one has missing values

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am trying to create a new column based on both columns. Say I want to create a new column z, and it should be the value of y when it is not missing and be the value of x when y is indeed missing. So in this case, I expect z to be `[1, 8, 10, 8]`.

```
   x   y
0  1 NaN
1  2   8
2  4  10
3  8 NaN
```

Comment: Related: [Replace NaN in one column with value from corresponding row of second column](/q/29177498/4518341) (same idea, but this is in-place instead of a new column)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The new column `'z'` get its values from column `'y'` using `df['z'] = df['y']`. This brings over the missing values so fill them in using `fillna` using column `'x'`. Chain these two actions:

```
>>> df['z'] = df['y'].fillna(df['x'])
>>> df
   x   y   z
0  1 NaN   1
1  2   8   8
2  4  10  10
3  8 NaN   8
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use `apply` with option `axis=1`. Then your solution is pretty concise.

```
df[z] = df.apply(lambda row: row.y if pd.notnull(row.y) else row.x, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `np.where`:

```
In [3]:

df['z'] = np.where(df['y'].isnull(), df['x'], df['y'])
df
Out[3]:
   x   y   z
0  1 NaN   1
1  2   8   8
2  4  10  10
3  8 NaN   8
```

Here it uses the boolean condition and if true returns `df['x']` else `df['y']`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say DataFrame is called `df`. First copy the `y` column.

```
df["z"] = df["y"].copy()
```

Then set the nan locations of z to the locations in x where the nans are in z.

```
import numpy as np
df.z[np.isnan(df.z)]=df.x[np.isnan(df.z)]


>>> df 
   x   y   z
0  1 NaN   1
1  2   8   8
2  4  10  10
3  8 NaN   8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but would this be what you're looking for?

"if y[i]" will skip if the value is none.

```
for i in range(len(x));
    if y[i]:
        z.append(y[i])
    else:
        z.append(x[i])
```

Comment: it doesn't work. For some reason it never hits the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method does almost exactly this. The only caveat is that `update` will do so in place so you must first create a copy:

```
df['z'] = df.x.copy()
df.z.update(df.y)
```

In the above example you start with `x` and replace each value with the corresponding value from `y`, as long as the new value is not `NaN`.