# Create new number variable using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df given below.

df

```
VAR FLAG
A      1
A      1
A      1
B      1
B      1
B      0
B      0
B      1
B      1
B      1
B      0
C      0
C      0
```

I want to create a new variable named FLAG1 using VAR and FLAG.
The final output given below.

Final Output: -

```
VAR FLAG    FLAG1
A      1        1
A      1        1
A      1        1
B      1        1
B      1        1
B      0        2
B      0        3
B      1        4
B      1        4
B      1        4
B      0        5
C      0        1
C      0        2
```

Comment: what exactly the logic here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: create a new column from existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265723/python-create-a-new-column-from-existing-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using this bit of logic:

```
df['FLAG1'] =  (df.groupby('VAR')['FLAG'] 
                  .transform(lambda x: ((x != x.shift()) | (x == 0)).cumsum()))
```

Output:

```
   VAR  FLAG  FLAG1
0    A     1      1
1    A     1      1
2    A     1      1
3    B     1      1
4    B     1      1
5    B     0      2
6    B     0      3
7    B     1      4
8    B     1      4
9    B     1      4
10   B     0      5
11   C     0      1
12   C     0      2
```

Comment: Excellent answert to the missing question (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

Try something new `factorize`

```
pd.Series(zip(df['FLAG'].eq(0).cumsum(),df.FLAG)).groupby(df['VAR']).transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
Out[72]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    5
11    1
12    2
dtype: int32
```